# Create an empty html file with php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a blank html file through php. I wrote some code but it seems not to be working. This is my code:

```
            $filename = 'test.html';        
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");       
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

When I click the link that would create this file, it gives me an html file but when I see the source it shows the source code of the page where i requested this.

Is there any reason why this wont work? Also, what is faster? To generate an html file everytime a user asks or to just pull a created empty file and just rename it when the user asks? Thanks!

Comment: 1)When I click, it downloads a file but if i see the source it gives me the source code of the site i requested this download from. 2) I want to make a verification file like google webmaster tools.3) I have no idea what 25% means

Comment: @raygo: look at that 25% under your name in this question, then go read the site's FAQs: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after sending the headers to stop any more data from being output. This will also stop execution of your PHP script:

```
$filename = 'test.html';        
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");       
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
exit();
```

Comment: That worked! Is there a reason why the file is still 1kb and not 0kb?! Thanks!

Comment: @raygo I have no idea why it would be 1 kb. It should be 0 bytes. Try manually adding `header("Content-Length: 0");` before you exit to see if that fixes it.

Comment: it's still 1 kb. Not sure why

Answer (score 13):

You may want to use the fopen function:

```
$file = fopen("test.html", 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($file);
```

This should create a file named test.html in the same path as the .php file that executed the code

Comment: op wants an empty .html file created on the client side. Otherwise there'd be no point in all those headers.

Answer (score 8):

For those that stumbled on this question like I did for creating a fully empty file in PHP, a very short solution is doing the following:

```
file_put_contents('test.html', '');
```

To which you can simply link them to that file, to answer OP's question.

Comment: This creates the file but it returns false, which is problematic.

Comment: @KevinHJ It actually returns `0` on success and `false` on failure: So you need to use `!== false` to determine success.

Comment: (red face) Ah yes indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the answer with most votes but for me personally this code worked better.

```
file_put_contents('test.html', '');
```

I am sure you can try this out for making perfect use of static files such as sitemap.xml and more...

Comment: This answer is the same as (or very similar to) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66107030/8517948). It would be better to upvote that answer instead of posting it again. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers that helped you.